# Regex for find data

Tags: java

I have used this `(?:#\d{7})` regex for extracting only 7 digit after `'#'`.

For example I have string something like `"#1234567890"`. After using the above patterrn I will get 7 digit after `'#'`.

Now the problem is : I have string something like that `"Referenc number #1234567890"`
where `"Referenc number #"` fixed.

Now I am finding for regex which can return the `1234567` number from the above string. 
I have a one file which contains above string and there are also other data available.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
    String ref_no = "Referenc number #123456789";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Referenc number #([0-9]{7})");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(ref_no);
    while (m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

Comment: This will also accept if I put this data : Referenc1 number #123456789

Comment: sorry i didn't understood your question??

Comment: If I used String ref_no = "Referenc_1 number #123456789"; then it will return 1234567 this number but here we used Referenc_1 number this string which does not match with "Referenc number". In my case Referenc number # this is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The ?: should make your group "non-capturing", so if you add that separately around the hash sign, it should used for matching but excluded from capture.

```js
(?:#)(\d{7})
```

Answer (score 0):

If the String always starts with `Referenc number #` you could just use the following code:

```
String text = "Referenc number #1234567890";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{7}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```